# expl3: Split to sequence for every new line

Tags: expl3

There are of course other packages to achieve this effect, but I would like to do it in `expl3`.

What I am trying to do in this MWE is to create a function which puts its input into a sequence, and splits it for every new line.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{+mm}{%
    \begingroup
  \ttfamily
        \seq_new:N \l_troll_seq
        \endlinechar=,
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_troll_seq {,} {#1}
        \seq_item:Nn \l_troll_seq {#2}
    \endgroup
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

Should output ``Bar Foo'':

\foo{
Bar Foo
Baz Bar}{1}

Should output ``Baz Bar'':

\foo{
Bar Foo
Baz Bar}{2}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Input is not controlled by me, and could include spaces and most regular symbols.

Comment: `\endlinechar=,` should be `\endlinechar=\`,` (it is an integer register) but you can not do this inside the argument of any command you have to do it _before_ the argument is parsed, otherwise the ends of lines are already gone. Can you not use space rather than eol?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm afraid I cannot change the input.

Comment: but the input here would work if you split on space. does your real input have spaces on the lines?

Comment: yes, the real input would have spaces and other unknown symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the interpretation of end of line before the argument is parsed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
        \seq_new:N \l_troll_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{%
    \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \endlinechar=`\,
   \fooo}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fooo}{+mm}{%
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_troll_seq {,} {#1}
        \seq_item:Nn \l_troll_seq {#2}
    \endgroup
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

Should output ``Bar'':

\foo{%
Bar
Baz}{1}

Should output ``Baz'':

\foo{%
Bar
Baz}{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a `%` here to avoid a comma at the start otherwise you need to filter out empty entries